# Are the clouds in minecraft the same for all clients on a server or are they client-only?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if the clouds on a Minecraft server were the same for multiple people or is it a client-only thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clouds are rendered on the client-side. Here is a quote from the Minecraft wiki

> Since clouds are rendered client-side, the position of clouds is different for each player on a server.